# Display Temperature Node-Red Raspberry Pi Sensehat Using Exec Node

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, iot, node-red, temperature

I am trying to display the current temperature every 5 seconds from a raspberry pi sensehat using the exec node with the function 'vcgencmd measure_temp'.

I want the output to display as {d: temp: 50} and display as a graph on the Watson IoT output node.

My current flow is shown in the photo attached below and my current code in the function node is as follows:

msg.payload = {'d' : {'temp' : msg.payload}};
return msg;

It is currently returning
{ d: *object* }

Any ideas? I have tried with a JSON node and it has not worked.

[image: Current Flow]

Answer (score 0):

You basically returning the object instead of a string. So as soon as you stringify your object it should be displayed correctly. Insert in the function node the following code:

```
msg.payload = {'d' : {'temp' : JSON.stringify(msg.payload)}}; return msg;
```

transform object into String:

```
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Using the code above it is still not working. I tried: `msg.payload = {'d' : {'temp' : JSON.stringify(msg.payload)}}; return msg;` as well as `msg.payload=JSON.stringify(msg.payload); msg.payload = {'d' : {'temp' : msg.payload}}; return msg; `